# How to identify the first date within a series of dates within the same case?

Tags: spss

This is probably a rather simple problem...
I am trying to identify the first date in a series of dates with in each case number and calculate the number of days between the rest of the date records to the first date record within each case. 
the data structure is as follows.

```
Client_ID  Transaction_date
Casenum1  Date1
Casenum1  Date2
Casenum1  Date3
Casenum1  Date4
Casenum1  Date5
Casenum2  Date1
Casenum3  Date2
Casenum4  Date3
Casenum5  Date4
Casenum6  Date5
```

I have tried to sort the data by case numbers in SPSS, I'm stuck on what to do with the date calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will first Identify the earliest date for each Client_ID and put it in a new variable, then calculate the difference in days between each date and the earliest date:

```
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables /break Client_ID /first_date=min(Transaction_date).
compute days_between=datediff(Transaction_date, first_date, "days").
```